# Which Data Type is Suitable for This Category/Sub-Category Behavior?

Tags: asp.net, database, types

I want to create a category and sub-category functionality in a web application of .NET Core MVC. I am thinking how I can pull it off such category and sub-category functioanlity behavior.

The behavior of the categories in the app would be like this

Suppose we have four categories:

- Finance
- Strategy
- Corporate

So, if someone clicks Finance then can choose Strategy or Corporate category. Similarly, if choose Strategy, then can choose Finance, but not category now. Then, if someone choose Corporate then can choose from Strategy and then finance.

Can anyone help me simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try
Composite data types‎

Comment: Can you please give a simple example. How it will work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/composite-data-types